# How to send an email automatically android

Tags: java, android, email

I'm kinda of new in android. How can i send an email automatically without a contact chooser. 
I write a list of e-mails in edittext and an message and then i want to send to every email address. 
How can i do that?

Comment: have you tried with `mailTo:` using intent?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a)

Answer (score 0):

```
 String[] TO = {""};
      String[] CC = {""};
      Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

      emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
      emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
      emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, TO);
      emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, CC);
      emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Your subject");
      emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Email message goes here");

      try {
         startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
         finish();
         Log.i("Finished sending email...", "");
      } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There is no email client installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Debora

One way where I have implemented this scenario is I created an `editText` for user where he/she supposed to enter email id.

After app level email id validation. I used to call my server api where i post the email ids along with content and subject and then server was responsible for sending mail.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this code

```
    final Intent emailIntent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
    emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "appsupport@YOUR_DOMAIN.com",....... }); //Heare you can add the list of email address you have
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Mail subject");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Mail content");
    try{
           startActivity(emailIntent);
    }catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){

    }
```

If you want to send the email with out user interaction then check the link:https://www.mindstick.com/Articles/1673/sending-mail-without-user-interaction-in-android

Comment: I used this but this shows a popup to choose the app that i want to send from and i dont want that. i want to send it automatically

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps mentioned below. It will send the email directly if app is connected to working internet. Don't forget to add INTERNET permission.

**1.** Add Mail.java to your code

**2.** Add jar files [mail.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/mail/mail.jar.zip),  [activation.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/activation/activation.jar.zip),  additionnal.jar

**3.** Use following code send an email, change email id and password.

```
String sub="Thank you for your online registration" ; 
Mail m = new Mail("emailid", "password"); 

String[] toArr = {"testecn2@gmail.com",sEmailId};
m.setFrom("testecn2@gmail.com"); 

m.setTo(toArr);
m.setSubject(sub);
m.setBody(msg);             

try{

    if(m.send()) { 
       //successful
    } else { 
      //failure
    } 
} catch(Exception e) { 

    Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e); 
}
```

**Mail.java**

```
   package com.example.mail;

   import java.util.Date;
   import java.util.Properties;

   import javax.activation.CommandMap;
   import javax.activation.DataHandler;
   import javax.activation.DataSource;
   import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
   import javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap;
   import javax.mail.BodyPart;
   import javax.mail.Multipart;
   import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
   import javax.mail.Session;
   import javax.mail.Transport;
   import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
   import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
   import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
   import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

   public class Mail extends javax.mail.Authenticator { 
         private String _user; 
         private String _pass; 

         private String[] _to; 

         private String _from; 

         private String _port; 
         private String _sport; 

         private String _host; 

         private String _subject; 
         private String _body; 

         private boolean _auth; 

         private boolean _debuggable; 

         private Multipart _multipart; 


       public Mail() { 
          _host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // default smtp server 
          _port = "465"; // default smtp port 
          _sport = "465"; // default socketfactory port 

          _user = ""; // username 
          _pass = ""; // password 
          _from = ""; // email sent from 
          _subject = ""; // email subject 
          _body = ""; // email body 

          _debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off 
          _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on 

          _multipart = new MimeMultipart(); 

          // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a handler for the        multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added. 
          MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap(); 
       mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html"); 
       mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml"); 
       mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-  handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain"); 
       mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed"); 
       mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content- handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822"); 
        CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc); 
       } 

     public Mail(String user, String pass) { 
      this(); 

      _user = user; 
       _pass = pass; 
     } 

    public boolean send() throws Exception { 
       Properties props = _setProperties(); 

      if(!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0 && !_from.equals("") &&   !_subject.equals("") /*&& !_body.equals("")*/) { 
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this); 

        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session); 

         msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from)); 

        InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length]; 
         for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) { 
          addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]); 
        } 
          msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo); 

        msg.setSubject(_subject); 
        msg.setSentDate(new Date()); 

      // setup message body 
      BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
        messageBodyPart.setText(_body); 
        _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 

         // Put parts in message 
        msg.setContent(_multipart); 

        // send email 
        Transport.send(msg); 

        return true; 
       } else { 
         return false; 
       } 
      } 

    public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception { 
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename); 
          messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source)); 
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename); 

       _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 
     } 

      @Override 
      public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() { 
         return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass); 
      } 

       private Properties _setProperties() { 
       Properties props = new Properties(); 

        props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host); 

      if(_debuggable) { 
        props.put("mail.debug", "true"); 
      } 

      if(_auth) { 
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 
       } 

        props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port); 
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport); 
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"); 
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false"); 

        return props; 
       } 

   // the getters and setters 
      public String getBody() { 
       return _body; 
     } 

     public void setBody(String _body) { 
      this._body = _body; 
     }

      public void setTo(String[] toArr) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this._to=toArr;
     }

    public void setFrom(String string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this._from=string;
    }

    public void setSubject(String string) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       this._subject=string;
    }
```

}